# How to explicitly name the database when using Entity Framework Migrations 4.3

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've recently started using Entity Framework migrations and noticed that the database name is not pulling through for me when I run the `Update-Database` command.

My connectionstring is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataContext" connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The very first time I run *Update-Database* my database is created with the correct name *TestDB*. However, as soon as I make a change to one of my entities it will not update any longer for me unless I add a Start Up Project Name (I'm using a multi project solution):

```
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName "TestDB.Data"
```

This then makes another new database which migrations will always continue to use. I don't mind having to put in the *StartUpProjectName* command but is there a way to override the default name for the database this produces? It always creates the database as

```
TestDB.Data.DataContext
```

Is there a way to ensure that the database created when passing the StartUpProject name is just called *TestDB* or is this a limitation of using the StartUpProjectName setting?

As a note, I think the reason I need to specify the StartUpProjectName is that I have a multilayer project setup. The Migrations Configuration file is in my 'Data' project, the entities/models are in my 'Domain' project, etc. I also do not currently have any initialize options in my Global.asax.cs file as I would have used previously on code first ef 4.2. So in my project I just have a DataContext in my Data project and the Migrations Configuration in that project also.

**EDIT:**

Since I originally setup this question I stumbled onto the 'correct' way to name a database in a multiproject solution. While the answer below will work it does mean you are duplicating your web.config in another area which isn't an ideal solution. Instead you can just put the name into your DbContext by doing something like this (DataContext is just the name I used in my project):

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DatabaseNameHere")
    { }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Table2> Table2 { get; set; }

    public virtual void Commit()
    {
        base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Rich

Comment: Additionally, I found this article helpful. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When doing `update-database` you should specify the project that contains the migrations. Make sure that you have an `app.config` file in that project that contains the correct connection string.

When splitting up an application over several projects, the connection string used when running the app is the one of the project started. When migrating, the connection string used is the one of the project containing the migrations.

When I did a similar setup I had to add the connection string in two places. A bit awkward, but it works.

Comment: Just tested that out and it worked! Thanks for the suggestion - would never have figured out to put the connection string in the other project! Thanks again :)

Comment: I put my connection strings in a separate connection strings file, which is referenced in the web project. I then link to that connection strings file from my other project, which avoids having to duplicate connection strings across projects.

Comment: It looks like Package Manager Console ignores the current build configuration in Visual Studio. Is this expected behavior? I am largely interested in picking up the right connection string, but there might be other differences in the project itself. How Package Manager Console decides what exe/dll to pick?

Answer (score 105):

You can avoid managing it in app.config by offering it as a parameter:

```
Update-Database -Verbose 
 -ConnectionString "CONNECTIONSTRING" 
 -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
 -StartupProjectName WEBSITE_PROJECT -ProjectName MIGRATION_PROJECT
```

Easy-piezy, if you love to type endlessly.

Comment: what if it can't find "System.Data.SqlClient"?

Comment: Is there any way that this can be defined on the web.config from the Startup Project? I want my build server to automatically push the migration changes to my database, but isn't allowing me to do so

Comment: If you're trying to pull the Connection String from the Web.config, you should use `-ConnectionStringName "DefaultConnection"`

Comment: You can get a list of all of command line options here:  https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Update-Database

Comment: In 2020 this list of params doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the following error is thrown in Package Manager Console(PMC):  Update-Database : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ConnectionString'.

Answer (score 26):

You can have your connection string stored in the web.config in your website project and the DBContext and migration files in another project and still share the same connection string. However you need to make sure that as well as setting the Data project (or whatever project has the DBContext etc. in it) as the default project for the Package Manager Console, you **ALSO need to make sure that your website is set to the Default StartUp Project!!!**

I cannot see this documented anywhere, but a frantic 24 hours of not being able to figure out why my migrations where suddenly being applied to a SQLExpress db, led me to this conclusion.

Comment: An +1 two years later, because the bolded part above is exactly what I needed after my own frantic 24 hour search!

Comment: Thanks! The connection string is read from the startup project's app.config/web.config.

Comment: Either set the Default StartUp Project or set the  -StartUpProjectName property in the EF migrations commands.

Comment: Well that's ridiculous but exactly the problem I had too. Never would have guessed! Granted I could have specified as a command line switch but for the life of me I could not figure out why I've never had to in the past. Guess I've just always been lucky. :)

Answer (score 12):

## I tried with Latest EF5 from Nuget.

However `Update-Database` does not read the `App.config` from the project that contain the migrations (just like the answer 1 year ago) but it will only read `*.config` from **start up project**. It is great but I discover how `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` find a suitable connection string here:

1. It trying to get "DefaultConnection" connection string first
2. Then it is trying to get the connection string name based on context class name. E.g. I have the `MyContext` class derived from `DbContext` so I can use the "MyContext" connection string name. Useful when I have multiple db connections.
3. If both the above connection string names are not found, it will fail and show no "DefaultConnection" connection string unless you supply the `-ConnectionStringName` parameter. See `get-help Update-Database` to view the help page in the Package Manager Console.

There is no retry or fallback attempt, so if the "DefaultConnection" contains a wrong connection string, it will simply show an error.

If both DefaultConnection and context name exist in the connection strings, DefaultConnection will take precedence.

I would prefer #2 become the first try because the name is more specific but the above steps is what EF5 Migrations do when trying to connect to the db.

Comment: I was running into the same issue and found out, similar to this poster, that migrations use a connection string in the start up project, and the name of the connection string is the same name as the  context.

Comment: This is really weird. It always read connectionString from Startup project config file. if not found than create database with the DbContext name.

Answer (score 0):

With dotnet 7, non of the above worked for me.

Instead, I explicitly specified the connection string as an argument.

e.g.

update-database -Connection "your connection string"

I prefer this way because it is clear what connection string I use, in particular, if you update the database in Production like me, you may not want to guess which connection string is loaded.