# EF6 Migration creating another database on update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am running the database update through Migrations but the EF is creating a database with the name of my connection string, rather than creating with the name of the database.

The correct would be to create the database with the *METIS* name, but are creating as *MetisConnectionString*.

What am I doing wrong?

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionString>
    <add name="MetisConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=METIS;User ID=metis_usr;Password=metis_usr;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionString>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
public class MetisDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public MetisDataContext() 
            : base("MetisConnectionString")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMapping());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327409/)?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I saw, but I was not wanting to believe it was. I've seen several codes that the ConnectionString name was on the base. But it worked! Found this link also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the name of your database to Entity Framework. So by convention EF will use your connection string. You can change this by specifying as in the connection string below

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MetisConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseNameHere;User ID=metis_usr;Password=metis_usr;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Constructor should read as below

```
   public MetisDataContext() 
            : base("name=MetisConnectionString")
   {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   }
```

Comment: I changed to this connection string and the behavior was the same.

Comment: Change your constructor to specify the name of the connection string and use the connection string as above